# Facebook photo sharing (& October 2013 breaking changes)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm building on a website for a client and the core functionality of it is to share photos with other users over Facebook.
So, what I've done is:

- user picks a photo he likes and clicks the "share" button
- script triggers Facebook "Friend Picker" popup
- user picks a friend he wants to share the photo with and clicks "OK"
- script triggers ajax request to the server which uploads the specific photo on the timeline of chosen friend

Here's the php photo sharing code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$body = array(
               'source'  => '@' . CURR_DIR . $photo->path,
               'message' => ''
             );

if ($user_id) 
{
    try
    {
        $result = $facebook->api('/' . $fbid . '/photos', 'post', $body);
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

So far this works beautifully, so my question is:

After the Facebook's "[October 2013 breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/)", they will be "removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API".
They advise usage of [feed dialog's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) from that point on.
So - how to upload a photo on a specific user's timeline using feed dialog's?
Is this even possible (because looking at the [feed documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), I don't think it is...)?

Comment: How would you get permission?

Comment: Well, if they're leaving the feed option - that means it'll be possible to post messages to users timelines.. So my question is, if that will be possible - will posting photos be possible as well?

Comment: My impression is that Facebook is removing the ability for people to post photos on other people's timelines.  Good riddance, I say.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, but my client has that request and I'm just here to check out what can be done about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So - how to upload a photo on a specific user's timeline using feed dialog's? Is this even possible

No, its not possible. I think you are now left with just one option- to post the photo on the user's wall (instead of friends'), and tag him/her on the photo. To tag friends, you have to use parameter: `tags`. Ref: [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)